# Store and retrieve data in redis

Tags: redis

How can I store the following structure in redis and get a specific output:

```
projects is the main category.
projects has categories each category has a list of data.

projects:catega contains: id: 1 values {id: 123, name: 'bla'}
                          id: 2 values {id: 124, name: 'bla1'}
projects:categb contains: id: 1 values {id: 125, name: 'bla2'}
                          id: 2 values {id: 126, name: 'bla4'}
```

I want to be able to get all the by selecting projects all the categories and their data like:

```
{catega: [{id...}, {id...}], categb: [{id...}, {id...}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Redis can store hash keys not complex objects, however, you can workaround that using below

1- restructure your object to be simpler such as

instead of

```
project1:
{
catega: 
    [{id: 123, name: 'bla'}, {id: 124, name: 'bla1'}], 
    [{id: 123, name: 'bla'}, {id: 124, name: 'bla1'}]
categb: 
    [{id: 123, name: 'bla'}, {id: 124, name: 'bla1'}], 
    [{id: 123, name: 'bla'}, {id: 124, name: 'bla1'}]
}
```

To be

```
project1:
{
categaID123: '{name:bla, age:15, salary:20}',
categaID124: '{name:blo, age:12, salary:21}',

categbID123: '{name:bla, age:15, salary:20}',
categbID124: '{name:bla, age:15, salary:20}',

}
```

2- You can set the hash as follows

```
hset project2 categorybID123 "{name:bla, age:15, salary:20}"
```

Or you can set all keys in one shot but using HMSET

3- You can retrieve the data in one call

```
hget project2 categorybID123
```

Hope this helps